# How to scrape table which is dynamically generated by Javascript

Tags: r, web, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I am a beginner in R and was trying to extract different table data from different Websites. I was able to perform the basic data scraping, but I am stuck while trying to extract data from the following table.

url: https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/equities_stock_watch.htm?cat=N

I tried using the `html_read` & `html_nodes` function using css and xpath but it does not return a value. Could anyone advise me on how to proceed ?

Comment: Have you tried using SelectorGadget as a browser add-on to identify the css/xpath? Usually SelectorGadget is spot on for `rvest`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scraping an interactive table in R with rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328819/scraping-an-interactive-table-in-r-with-rvest)

Comment: maybe `jsonlite::read_json("https://www.nseindia.com/homepage/Indices1.json", simplifyVector=TRUE)$data`? and maybe `jsonlite::read_json("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/niftyStockWatch.json", simplifyVector=TRUE)`?

Comment: @chinsoon12 : Thank you. I was able to get the results using read_json.

Comment: @chinsoon12 : But can you tell me on how you identified the json page ?

Comment: check out the Network tab in the Inspector in Chrome

Comment: Rohit you might like to edit your title to *"How to scrape table which is dynamically generated by Javascript"*. This will make it easier for others to find this in future.

Answer (score 3):

So the problem you're facing is that rvest will read the source of a page, but it won't execute the javascript on the page. The table is created by executing javascript *once the source has been loaded*.

Your best option is to look into RSelenium. This is because RSelenium actually launches and drives a browser window, once the javascript has executed you can query the current source (what you would see if you right click in Chrome and select Inspect).

However, RSelenium was pulled from CRAN because some dependencies were pulled from CRAN, so you'll probably need to use MRAN to install it.

Comment: Thank you. "The table is created by executing javascript once the source has been loaded." - This cleared my doubts on why rvest was not working.